# Extract string from http response in java client

Tags: java, web-services, httpresponse

I want to extract the string returned from java web service in java client. The string returned from java web service is as follows:

```
{"Name":"Raj Johri","Email":"mailraj@server.com","status":true}
```

Which is a Json string format. I have written client code to extract this string as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/JsonWebService/services/JsonWebService/getData");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    HttpResponse httpres = httpClient.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = httpres.getEntity();
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();
    System.out.println("json:" + json);
}
```

I am getting following print on the console for json as:

```
json:<ns:getDataResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.jsonweb.com"><ns:return>{"Name":"Raj Johri","Email":"mailraj@server.com","status":true}</ns:return></ns:getDataResponse>
```

Please tell me how to extract the string

```
{"Name":"Raj Johri","Email":"mailraj@server.com","status":true}
```

which is the actual message. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dirty way to do this (beside the xml parsing way)
if you are getting the same XML every time,
you can use `split()`

```
String parts[] = json.split("<ns:return>");
parts = parts[1].split("</ns:return>");
String jsonPart = parts[0];
```

now `jsonPart` should contain only `{"Name":"Raj Johri","Email":"mailraj@server.com","status":true}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, The respons is as type of **xml**, and your **json** is in the `<ns:return>` **node** , so i suggest you to enter in depth of the xml result and simply get your json from the `<ns:return>` node.

**Note:**
I suggest you to try to specifying that you need the response as **JSON type**:

```
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried that but gives an exception xml:lang="en-US">com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException