# take the json from ksoap2 response

Tags: android, json, ksoap2

I have an application that call a webservice and response with specific data

everything working good, but! I can't take the json array from this response

that's my response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <usersGetAllManagersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <usersGetAllManagersResult>[{"User_P_ID":1,"User_ID":44,"Ar_Name":"خالد","En_Name":"Khalid"}]</usersGetAllManagersResult>
        </usersGetAllManagersResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: you have to parse the XML to get the content OR you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522588/extract-string-from-http-response-in-java-client/27522802#27522802, replace `<ns:return>` with `<userGetAll...>`

Comment: thank you mate for the replay , But !! that's crash my app :(

Comment: did you replace `json.split...` with `YOR_VARIABLE_NAME.split...`

Comment: yup . i replace it and also replace the return with my tag name

Comment: did you replace the second `split`? i mean the closing tag `</...`, otherwise i am not sure why u got crash, check the logcat or debug it

Comment: finally its work man , many thanks ... please post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I've manually inlined the code from your image into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to parse the XML to get the content OR you can use 
use `split()`

```
String resp = "<userGetAll...> ....</userGetAll...> ......";
String parts[] = json.split("<userGetAll...>");
parts = parts[1].split("</userGetAll...>");
String jsonPart = parts[0];
```

`jsonPart`  is what you are looking for.